# Migration SharePoint 2010 to 2013 - Exception Upgrade-SPSite & SPSiteHealthChecker

Tags: 2013, site-collection, migration, upgrade

A site collection can not be upgraded.

[image: Powershell Eception]

```
Upgrade-SPSite -identity <site collection url> -VersionUpgrade -Unthrottled
```

When I performed the command above, the exception below was thrown.

> Upgrade-SPSite : SPSiteHealthChecker: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException exception thrown in SPSiteHealthChecker.Test():
>    Der Vorgang kann nicht erfolgreich beendet werden.
>   Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut.
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetWebListPermMask(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_EffectiveBasePermissions()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions permissionMask)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurableObject.CheckPermissions(SPBasePermissions permissionMask)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.ValidateSecurityOnOperation(SPOperationCode code, SPSecurableObject obj)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityOnOperationScope..ctor(SPOperationCode code, SPSecurableObject obj)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeCollection.FetchCollection(IList`1 exceptions)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_ContentTypes()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SiteHealth.SPSiteHealthConflictingContentTypeRule.ProcessWeb(SPWeb spWeb)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SiteHealth.SPSiteHealthRule.ProcessWebs(SPWeb spWeb)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SiteHealth.SPSiteHealthRule.ProcessWebs(SPWeb spWeb)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SiteHealth.SPSiteHealthRule.ProcessWebs(Boolean repair)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SiteHealth.SPSiteHealthConflictingContentTypeRule.Test()
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SiteHealth.SPSiteHealthChecker.Test(Guid _ruleId, Boolean _repair, Boolean
>   _runAlways, SPLongOperationState longOperation, String statusFormat)
>    SPSite="http://www.test.sp.group.baywa.com/sites/events"
>    ruleId=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>    repair=True
>    CompatibilityLevel=14
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Upgrade-SPSite -Identity http://www.test.mysharepoint.com/sites/events -Versio ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletUpgradeSite:SPCmdletUpgradeSite) [Upgrade-SPSite], S
>      PSiteHealthCheckerException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletUpgradeSite

Site collection health check is also broken.

[image: Site collection health checks]
[image: Site collection health checks]
[image: 404]

Any help and explaination would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: can you run the test-spsite against that site colleciton

Comment: No, I got the same exception:

PS C:\Users\schorern\Desktop> Test-SPSite -Identity http://www.test.mysharepoint.com/sites/events
Test-SPSite : SPSiteHealthChecker: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException exception thrown in SPSiteHealthChecker.Test():
 Der Vorgang kann nicht erfolgreich beendet werden.
Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetWebListPermMask(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_EffectiveBasePermissions()

Comment: Do u still have old farm? Looks like something corrupted while migration?

Comment: Yes, I still have the old farm. I remigrated the site collection from sp2010 farm to sp2013 twice but still got the same exception.

Comment: Can u run test-spaite in old farm against that site collection, looks like something wrong at source

Comment: Nope, because the cmdlet was introduced in SP2013.
Thanks for your effort tho

Comment: You are right, i know you fix the issue but just for fun....this way you can check the health of site collection....Get-SPContentDatabase | ForEach-Object { Test-SPContentDatabase $_.ID }

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE
I had no trouble mounting the database but upgrading the siteversion. -> test-spcontentdatabse and mount-spcontentdatabase = ok, upgrade-spsite, move-spsite, copy-spsite, test-spsite = exception above.
Thanks a lot for you time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new site with a new content db and migrated the contents and subsites with 3rd party tool (in my case ShareGate). Then I could upgrade the site collection.
But my client doesn't want to buy a migration tool to migrate only one single site collection.

So I ended up using the export-spweb and import-spweb cmdlets to move the old contents to the new site collection and then performed the site upgrade.